# Query a user's Language on Exchange 2003 using WebDAV

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, webdav, exchange-server-2003

### How can I programatically query a user's Language/Locale/Region from Exchange 2003?

I'm using [Independentsoft's Exchange WebDAV](http://independentsoft.com/webdavex/index.html) api.  I'm trying to get a method signature like:

```
public string GetUsersLanguage(string username, string password){
   //magic

   //return fr-FR, or en-US, or nl-NL, etc
}
```

Exchange 2003 will configure the default folders (Inbox, Calendar, etc) to match the user's locale the first time the mailbox is accessed.  So **Inbox** becomes **Postvak IN** for Dutch.  I'd prefer not to inspect the top level folders and match that against a lookup table; is there another way?

The WebDAV api has a property [getcontentlanguage](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#PROPERTY_getcontentlanguage) that looks like it should contain the associated language for a mailbox (or at least a top level folder like Inbox), but whenever I query for that field Exchange returns a 404:

[image: Fiddler Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get something close, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  Exchange 2003 OWA has a property `spellingdictionarylanguage` that *could* contain a close approximation to the user's culture.  I say *could* becuase this field if only set if the user has logged into OWA Premium (via IE in compatibility mode) and explicitly set the Spelling Dictionary.

```
Resource resource = new Resource(session);

var allProps = resource.GetProperties();

Console.WriteLine(
    "Culture (Best Guess via Spelling Langauge): " +
     allProps
         .Where(x => x.Name == "spellingdictionarylanguage")
         .Select(x => x.Value)
         .FirstOrDefault() ?? "");
```

**Hopefully there is still a better way to do this.**